# Как получить координаты по адресу APO яндекс карт?

Tags: яндекс-карты, yandex-geocoding-api, яндекс-карта-api

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?geocode='.urlencode('Москва').'&key='.urlencode('мой ключ').'&results=1');

var_dump($xml);
```

---

Ответ FALSE

Comment: Первое очевидное действие - посмотреть что же возвращает геокодер. И, кстати, вместо http лучше https

Comment: В том и дело, что ничего не выводит. Ответ var_dump() - bool(false)

Comment: Это вам simplexml_load_file выводит false, а не геокодер

Comment: Геокодер возвращает xml, там все норм. 
https://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?geocode=Москва&key5b406e28-3964-4611-9e52-9d2cc6ece976&results=1
Как с этим работать не понимаю?

Comment: А может этот лопдер с редиректом не дружит. Попробуйте https вместо http

Comment: Так и было, это ничего не меняет. пробовал.

Comment: ещё у вас параметр key, а должен быть apikey